# Longest path algorithm with "can" have loop and negative edge in certain amount step

Tags: graph, dijkstra, hamiltonian-cycle, longest-path

I've done my own research ,However I couldn't find a proper solution for my demand.

The problem is , I have a truck  which needs to spend it's load(let's say garbage). There are cities(node) and edges(way) which can be positive edge or negative . While truck takes the a way , it can  loose or have to get more(waste) depends on the selected way(edge). If it selected positive edge , it loose the waste exactly same amount of the selected way value. And vice versa.

So , truck driver has to make a certain amount of step(every step take a constant time whatever the value of the edge) and driver has limited time to come back his home(origin node)(time will be a given parameter)

So in this graph , we have nodes , we have edges which is one direction  to   , this edge can have negative or positive value , and in the graph there can be loops which driver is allowed to use or not to use . And nodes can point each other with different edges. (from A to B edge val is  5 ) (from B to A edge val is -3 and so on..)

**So I want to give to the driver the best way to spend it's maximum load in the best possible shortest time.**

So , the problem is this.

What I want is, note the actual code.

If you know the name of the problem you can specify , you're welcome.
If you'd like to share your own algorithm with pseudo code or just words. You're welcome ,too.
If you'd like to share a link which you think a similar problem is asked. You're also welcome.

And if you think it's not possible to solve. Please share your thoughts or a link that proves  .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Guys Still looking for a decent answer.

Comment: leute ich wirklich brauche einen antworte :p

Comment: Depth first? Transform into DAG and apply Johnson Algo https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm

Comment: "I've done my own research ,However I couldn't find a proper solution for my demand." So show some of the things you have found and explain how they did not help. This will provide some indirect context to your question and help helping you.